# Генерирование отчета на основе данных извлеченных JIRA REST API

Tags: rest, jira

Необходимо создать аналог отчетов из JIRA (страница проекта -> страница отчеты) - но только в "своем" приложении.
Копал в сторону JIRA REST API но ничего путного. Есть ли возможность извлечь данные через API и создать на их основе отчет?
Сталкивался кто-нибуть с такой задачей?

Answer (score 1):

Решаю подобную задачу выгрузкой напрямую из БД Jira (PostgreSQL) с помощью скрипта Autoit и далее формирование отчета в Excel.

JIRA REST API работает очень медленно с большими объемами данных, поэтому отказался от такого способа.

**Пример:**

Для соединения с БД использую [SQL UDF](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/51952-_sqlau3-adodbconnection/) и [ODBC драйвер PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/).

Пример запроса (список отработанного времени по сотрудникам за период):

```
$sql = "select to_char(w.startdate,'DD.MM.YYYY') as " & '"Дата"' & _ 
        ", c.display_name as " & '"Сотрудник"' & _ 
        ", p.pkey || '-' || j.issuenum as " & '"Заявка"' & _
        ", round(w.timeworked/60/60,3) as " & '"Часы"' & _ 
        ', it.pname as "Тип заявки"' & _
        ' from worklog w' & _
        ' left join jiraissue j on j.id = w.issueid' & _
        ' left join project p on j.project = p.id' & _
        ' left join cwd_user c on w.author = c.lower_user_name' & _                     
        ' left join issuetype it on j.issuetype = it.id' & _                        
        " where w.startdate >= '" & $DateFrom & " 00:00:00' and w.startdate <= '" & $DateTo & " 23:59:59'" & _
        ' order by c.display_name'
```

Выполняем запрос:

```
    #include "_sql.au3"

    $aLog = DB_query($sql)
    if not IsArray($aLog) Then          
        msgbox(0,"Not found", "Не найдено ни одной записи в выбранном периоде")         
    EndIf

    Func DB_query($query)
        local $aResult
        Consolewrite("Exec query: " & $query & @CRLF & @CRLF)
        _SQL_Startup()
        $SQL_LastConnection.Open("Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)};Server=" & $server & ";Database=" & $db & ";uid=" & $username & ";pwd=" & $password & ";")   
        _Sql_GetTable2d($SQL_LastConnection, $query, $aResult,$iRows, $iColumns)    
        Consolewrite("Duration: " & $timer_diff & @CRLF & @CRLF)
        _Sql_Close($SQL_LastConnection)
        if IsArray($aResult) Then
            return $aResult
        Else
            return 0
        EndIf
    EndFunc
```

Результат помещаем в Excel и строим сводную таблицу:

```
#include <Excel.au3>

$xlApp = _Excel_Open(False,False,True,True,True)
$oWorkbook = _Excel_BookNew($xlApp)
$xlApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = 0
_Excel_RangeWrite($oWorkbook,$oWorkbook.Activesheet,$aLog, "A1", Default, true)
$xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns("A:E").AutoFit
$bookName = $xlApp.activeworkbook.name
$xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.activesheet.name = "log"

$xlApp.Sheets.add
$xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.activesheet.name = "Таблица"
$slogName = $xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Item("log").name
$sUsedRange = $xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Item("log").usedrange.address(True, True, -4150)
$xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(1, $slogName & "!" & $sUsedRange, 5).CreatePivotTable($xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.activesheet.name & "!R3C1", "СводнаяТаблица1", 5)
$xlApp.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("СводнаяТаблица1").AddDataField($xlApp.Workbooks($bookName).ActiveSheet.PivotTables("СводнаяТаблица1").PivotFields("Часы"), "Сумма по часам", -4157)
$xlApp.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("СводнаяТаблица1").PivotFields("Сумма по часам").NumberFormat = "0,00"

With $xlApp.Workbooks($bookName).ActiveSheet.PivotTables("СводнаяТаблица1") 
    .PivotFields("Сотрудник").Orientation = 1
    .PivotFields("Сотрудник").Position = 1
    .PivotFields("Заявка").Orientation = 1
    .PivotFields("Заявка").Position = 2 
    .PivotFields("Сотрудник").AutoSort(2, "Сумма по часам")
EndWith
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы привели пример.

Comment: Добавил пример.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос с помощью Selenium и PhantomJS+GhostDriver